# How to realize lower() (postresql) in dbix:class

Tags: postgresql, dbix-class

I need the postgresql query:
`select  * from document where lower(app_period) = '2019-08-01 00:00:00+03';`

How it will look in dbix::class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DBIx::Class::Manual::Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Using-SQL-functions-on-the-left-hand-side-of-a-comparison) contains an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

In DBIx::Class it looks like:

```
$rs->search(
  \[ 'lower(app_period) = ?', $start ]
);
```

With some params:

```
$rs->search({ -and => [
  agreement_id => $id,
  \[ 'lower(app_period) = ?', $start ]
]});
```